# Form doesn't insert into the database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a one-page CRUD in CodeIgniter which only consist of not more than 5 fields. My problem is it doesn's insert its data in the database, I've been debugging this but I can't figure it out what is the problem. What did I miss?

Form:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="activity-item">
    <form id="agencyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-body">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="agency_id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input name="agency_name" id="agency_name" placeholder="Agency Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <?php echo form_error('agency_name','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input name="category" id="category" placeholder="Category" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <?php echo form_error('category','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <?php echo form_error('address','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input name="acronym" id="acronym" placeholder="Acronym" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <?php echo form_error('acronym','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit " id="btnSave" onclick="save(this.agencyForm); return false" class="btn btn-effect">Save</button>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        showAllAgency();
        //datatables
        table = $('#').DataTable({

            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],

            "ajax": {
                "url": "",
                /*<?php echo site_url('agency/list')?>*/
                "type": "POST"
            },

            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [-1], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            }, ],

        });

        //set input/textarea/select event when change value, remove class error and remove text help block
        $("input").change(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });
        $("textarea").change(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });
        $("select").change(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });

    });



    function add_person() {
        save_method = 'add';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
        $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
        $('#modal_form').modal('show');
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Agency');
    }

    function edit_person(id) {
        save_method = 'update';
        $('#form')[0].reset();
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
        $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

        //Ajax Load data from ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('agency/edit_agency/')?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {

                $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
                $('[name="agency_name"]').val(data.agency_name);
                $('[name="category"]').val(data.category);
                $('[name="address"]').val(data.address);
                $('[name="acronym"]').val(data.acronym);
                $('#modal_form').modal('show');
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Agency');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
    }

    function reload_table() {
        table.ajax.reload(null, false);
    }

    function save() {
        $('#btnSave').text('saving...');
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
        var url;

        if (save_method == 'add') {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('agency/save_c')?>";
        } else {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('agency/update_c')?>";
        }

        console.log($('#agencyForm').serialize());
        // alert($(agencyForm).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            // url: "<?php echo site_url('agency/save_c')?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#agencyForm').serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {

                if (data.status) {
                    alert('Successfully added the officer');
                    reload_table();

                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) {
                        $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                        $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                    }

                }
                $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
                $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable

            }
        });
    }


    function showAllAgency() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>agency/getAgency',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].agency_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].category + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].address + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].acronym + '</td>' +
                        // '<td>'+
                        //     '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].agency_id+'">Edit</a>'+
                        //     '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].agency_id+'">Delete</a>'+
                        // '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                }
                $('#showagency').html(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function save_c() {    
    var_dump($this - > input - > post(NULL, TRUE));
    $data = array(
        'agency_name' => $this - > input - > post('agency_name'),
        'category' => $this - > input - > post('category'),
        'address' => $this - > input - > post('address'),
        'acronym' => $this - > input - > post('acronym'),
    );
    $insert = $this - > agency - > save_now($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Model:

```
public function save_now($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

NOTE: It inserts data into the database when I change the URL like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // url: url,
    url: "<?php echo site_url('agency/save_c')?>",
```

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h26yc.png)

Comment: try to console.log(url) and check what url it shows

Comment: `if (save_method == 'add')`.. you're not defining `save_method` anywhere before your if-statement so that variable would be undefined. If the script continues, it would automatically get the update-url instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Sir the `var save_method;` is defined starting of the script. It's just I forgot to include.

Comment: Please copy/paste _all_ the relevant code into your question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I downloaded this code and modified based on my needs. This is a working crud using modal but I wanted to remove the modal on ADDING an item/agency. I already pasted all the code

Comment: You need to add more debugging in your code (through out the flow of the application) to figure out exactly where things go wrong. There are too many unknowns for us. It doesn't help that it's a modification of a script you downloaded from somewhere else, which we also know nothing about.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Sir, That's what I'm currently doing right now. I'm debugging it part by part. I'm stock at the add method without the modal. I just wanted to change the `add` method without the modal. Everything work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have ussue here. You haven't specify `save_method` anywhere. define `save_method` according to your logic or remove this if condition and  assign insertion url directly

```
if (save_method == 'add') {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('agency/save_c')?>";
} else {
     url = "<?php echo site_url('agency/update')?>";
}
```

You can do insertion directly

```
url = "<?php echo site_url('agency/save_c')?>";
```

Comment: According to your code it always execute `else part` where have you assign `add` to `save_method`?

Comment: the `add` part Sir is in the MODAL. I wanted to remove the modal in adding an item/agency. Just a one-page add option without the modal. I pasted all the script code